# Same color range for multiple scatterplots

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

When doing multiple scatterplots, I want the colors of the new plotted points to be in line with the same colorbar. I have my base plot (colors are stored in `y` array):

```
im = ax.scatter(embs[:,0],
           embs[:,1],
           edgecolor='k',
           linewidth=0.2,
           c=y
           )
```

[image]

Now I want to highlight a specific point, by plotting a red contour (I'm highlighting the yellow point top right):

```
ax.scatter(embs[5715][0],
            embs[5715][1],
            edgecolor='red',
            linewidth=0.3,
            c=y[5715]
            )
```

The problem is that its color now won't agree with the original one:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to fix this is to pass the `norm` of the object returned by your first `scatter` call as the `norm` of the second call.

This ensures that the range of data used for the first scatter plot is respected for the second one

e.g.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.random.normal(size=(2, 1000))
c = x ** 2 + y ** 2

cb = plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, ec="k")
plt.scatter(x[777], y[777], c=c[777], ec="r", norm=cb.norm)

plt.colorbar(cb)

plt.show()
```

which will give e.g.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, anyway I just sorted this issue by setting `facecolor='none'` on the second scatterplot, as my pure goal was to highlight the point.

Comment: I did initially think about that but if you have overlapping points it might not look so nice

Comment: Exactly!! Just noticed that and adopted your solution right away ^^ Many thanks again!